# How to solve this simple inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

$$(a+1)(a+2b)≤\frac{-1}{2}$$
I was solving a problem about quadratic equations and I needed to find the value of $a$ and $b$.

I used the discriminant to get an inequality and I simplified it to get the above inequality.

How to solve this?

Comment: Please show us the initial inequality as well and the quadratics.

Comment: @Rebellos I've posted the original question here: 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3666184/if-this-equation-in-x-has-real-roots-find-the-value-of-a-and-b

Comment: Then don't post the same question twice please.