# If this equation in x has real roots find the value of a and b.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics

$$ x^2+2(1+a)x+(3a^2+4ab+4b^2+2)=0$$

I tried to make an inequality using the discriminant and I simplified it to get
$$a^2+2ab+b^2+\frac{1}{2}≤0$$

But I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Check your computation of discriminant. I get $(a+2b)^2+(a-1)^2 \leq 0$. then $a=1,b=-2$.

Comment: @N.Quy please post that as an answer.

Comment: @N.Quy b should be $\frac{-1}{2}$?

Comment: @N.Quy if a=1 and b=-2 then the inequality simplifies to $9≤0$. How is this possible?

Comment: my mistake ^^ $b=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equation has a real root then the discriminant must be non-negative.

$$\Delta=4(1+a)^2-4(3a^2+4ab+4b^2+2) \geq 0$$
$$\iff 3a^2+4ab+4b^2-a^2-2a+1 \leq 0$$
$$ \iff (a-1)^2+(a+2b)^2 \leq 0$$
$$\iff a-1=a+2b=0$$
$$\iff a=1, b=-\frac{1}{2}$$